# How do I make a step-by-step scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, gsap, scrollmagic

How do I make scrolling stepwise?
I use GSAP and ScrollMagic for text appearance.
Example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcqyU.jpg)

Comment: Don't use ScrollMagic, use [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger). [Here's a basic demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/abdNRxX).

Comment: @ZachSaucier Oh, Yes, I should have thought of that myself. You helped me a lot, thank you very much!